# How to get global messages in compare products page, getMessagesBlock is empty

Tags: template, magento-1, session, messages, compare

I'm trying to get **global messages in compare products page**, but none of the messages get rendered, instead all of them appear in any subsequent page I'm going, after producing messages with for example removing product from comparsion. I understand that this is normal behaviour for Magento, because normally compare page has a popup template, but I `setTemplate` to `1column.phtml` in my `local.xml`. Now I need global messages to appear there too. I included:

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>
```

to `catalog/product/compare/list.phtml`, but messages only appear in any subsequent page and not in compare list page.
As I [found out from here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/219/is-it-possible-to-handle-success-error-messages-from-within-blocks), you can add custom messages. So I did

```
$this->getMessagesBlock()->addError('Test Error!');
echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
```

Now this custom error gets rendered as it should, but none of the other messages show. How could I get all session messages to be shown in compare page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For messages to appear you need to call this in the controller before calling `renderLayout()`

```
$this->initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
```

This will tell Magento to display the messages set for a particular session type. The example above tells Magento to display the messages set for the catalog session.
Other options are `customer/session`, `core/session`, `checkout/session`, `tag/session` and `adminhtml/session` and `admin/session` (for backend).
You can call this method with an array of parameters

```
$this->initLayoutMessages(array('catalog/session', 'customer/session'));
```

In conclusion, if you want messages displayed in the compare list you should override the product compare controller or use the event `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_product_compare_index` and init the session messages you need.